# How can I prove this statement about filters?

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, filters

I have the following question:

> Let $M$ be a finite set an $F$ a filter on $M$. Show that this filter has to be fixed

My Idea was the following:

*Since $M$ is finite also $P(M)$ is. But since $F\subset P(M)$ we have that $$|F|\leq |P(M)|=2^{|M|}$$i.e. $F$ is finite. So let us numerate all the elements in $F$, i.e. $$F=\{A_1,...A_n\}$$ we can indeed do this since $F\neq \emptyset$.  Now let us look at $$A_1\cap A_2\cap...\cap A_n\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,(1)$$ We know by thefinition of a filter that $$U,V\in F\Rightarrow U\cap V\in F$$Using this property we can proceede inductivly on the index in $(1)$ and get that $$\bigcap_{i=1}^n A_i\in F$$But since we know that $\emptyset \notin F$ we have that $\bigcap_{i=1}^n A_i\neq \emptyset$ and thus $F$ is fixed.*

Does this work like this or is it wrong?

Thank you for your help

Comment: It looks fine to me.

Comment: ah perfect thank you. But is it right that if $F$ would be infinite in general, then the argumentation would fail when we consider the infinite intersection? So it's similar to rings and $\sigma$-algebras from Analysis only with unions. I.e. in a ring we also don't know if the infinite union lies again in the ring, but for sigma algebras it is by definition so.

Comment: Yes, your argument would fail if $\mathcal F$ was infinite.

Comment: ah perfect! thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is true  and your proof valid. A filter $\mathcal F$ on a finite set $X$ is a subset of $\mathscr{P}(X)$ and hence is finite, i.e. $\mathcal{F}$ is a finite set of subsets. One axioms of filters tells us that $\mathcal{F}$ is closed under binary intersection, and indeed a standard induction argument (which is often skipped as too self-evident) shows that in fact $F_0:=\mathcal{F}$ is closed under all finite intersections, and in particular $\bigcap \mathcal{F} \in \mathcal F$. As $F_0 \neq \emptyset$ (a filter does not contain $\emptyset$ by another axiom), this means that $\mathcal F$ is a fixed filter (i.e. has non-empty intersection).

Using the enlargement axiom it is in fact easy to see that then the following holds:

$$\mathcal F = \{A \subseteq X\mid F_0 \subseteq A\}$$

Comment: perfect thanks!

Comment: @Wave Glad I could help!